# What necessary steps needs to be taken after inserting bulk data into cassandra using SSTableLoader?

Tags: cassandra, bulkinsert, datastax-java-driver, cqlsh

Newbie to cassandra here.

I have inserted 50Million records into cassandra by creating SSTables from a CSV files and then used SSTableLoader to load them up into the database.
Are there any post SSTableLoader steps thats needs to taken?
eg: Do a nodetool repair..etc

The problem that I am facing is that I am not able to retrieve some records when I try to query via secondary indexes, even though that record shows up in the list when querying for all records.

Eg: `select * from columfamily limit 50`

```
value1|value2.....|value25

value11|value22...|

.
.
. 50 records
```

And then when I query from one of these records with value2 as secondary index, it will return 0 rows.

```
Create index on columnfamily (column2)

select * from columnfamily where column2='value2';

0 Rows
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Index creation is asynchronous.  Did you wait for it to finish building?

Comment: Yes, waited for it to finish building.

Note: I did nodetool repair, restarted the server, and I am able to retrieve all the records that shows up in the list, but querying random records from the csv files doesnt return ~7/10 times.

Comment: @jbellis Are you sure about that? Because in my case, after loading millions of rows, sstableloader waits for the secondary index build to complete before exiting

Comment: "CREATE INDEX" is asynchronous.  Loading data into an existing index is not.